# $('iframe').load() in setInterval starts to repeat itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, setinterval

The content of my iframe.on('load', ... ) after every iteration of setInterval loop repeats itself once more as if every time my iframe is reloaded it remembers this reload and responds to it in next interation once again.

The logs are: 'loaded' in first step ... 'loaded' 'loaded' ... 'loaded' 'loaded' 'loaded' an so on.

**The code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

setInterval((function () {
    let i = 0;
    let iframe = $(document).find('iframe');

    return function () {
        i++;
        i = i % pages.length;
        // console.log(i);

        iframe.fadeOut().promise().done(() => {
            iframe.prop('width', pages[i].width)
                .prop('height', pages[i].height)
                // .prop('-webkit-transform','scale(0.28, 0.48)')
                .prop('src', pages[i].src);
            iframe.on('load', () => {
                iframe.fadeIn();
                console.log('loaded')
            });
        });
    }
})(), frameWindow_time);
});
```

Comment: *...setInterval starts to repeat itself* - this is a strong indicator that you are setting an event handler within the setInterval (and not clearing it first).

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear event listeners for iframe in each iteration, before binding a new one:

```
iframe.unbind( "load" );
```

example:

```
setInterval((function () {
    let i = 0;
    let iframe = $(document).find('iframe');
    iframe.unbind( "load" );

    return function () {
        i++;
        i = i % pages.length;
        // console.log(i);

        iframe.fadeOut().promise().done(() => {
            iframe.prop('width', pages[i].width)
                .prop('height', pages[i].height)
                // .prop('-webkit-transform','scale(0.28, 0.48)')
                .prop('src', pages[i].src);
            iframe.on('load', () => {
                iframe.fadeIn();
                console.log('loaded')
            });
        });
        // move();
    }
})(), frameWindow_time);
```

or you can move it outside the `setInterval()` function:

```
iframe  = $(document).find('iframe');
iframe.on('load', () => {
   iframe.fadeIn();
   console.log('loaded');
});
i=0
setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        i = i % pages.length;
        // console.log(i);

        iframe.fadeOut().promise().done(() => {
            iframe.prop('width', pages[i].width)
                .prop('height', pages[i].height)
                // .prop('-webkit-transform','scale(0.28, 0.48)')
                .prop('src', pages[i].src);
        });
        // move();
}, frameWindow_time);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great! However I had to put in inside the inner function, not just execute once.

Comment: Ok, put it inside:
return function () {
iframe.unbind( "load" );
...
}